# Do we need both "power" and "power analysis" tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Do we really need both of these tags? They seem very close to me.

Comment: They seem close to me too, & I'd be OK w/ it if they were merged. However, I do see them as being potentially distinct; **power** is a *property* of a test, whereas **power-analysis** is an *activity*. Eg, the distinction might be clearer in this thread: [Power of the t-test under unequal sample sizes](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63856/), which is tagged `[power-analysis]`, but should probably be tagged `[power]` instead under my way of thinking (I deferred to the OP, however).

Comment: Power could be the master. That would include the property and the activity (i.e. the analysis aspect would be implied in question body)

Answer (score 6):

As some people have stated in the comments, I think 'power' is the more appropriate parent, as there are some questions that pertain to power, like the power of a particular test, or what a given power implies, whereas 'power analysis' is something you do to a particular study.